# Hot deploy with WebLogic server?

Tags: java, deployment, weblogic

I have an enterprise application running on a WebLogic server.

When I modify any Java class, I have to build the `.ear` file and deploy to the server every time. Even for a small modification, I need to build the whole application and deploy to the server. The server is taking around 10 minutes to do this.

Is there any other way to do this?

When I was working with Tomcat, we used to update the `.class` files directly in the *`webapps`* project folder so that we didn't need to re-build the entire application.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes - there is a feature called FastSwap.

[Using FastSwap to speed up dev](http://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/using_fastswap_to_speed_up_dev)

[Using FastSwap Deployment to Minimize Redeployment](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/DEPGD/deployunits.htm#DEPGD153)

Comment: i am using eclipse weblogic plugin, with plugin how to run the WLS in developement mode?

Comment: Hi Jeff ..i am facing com.bea.wls.redef.ant.FastSwapTask cannot found ? could you give the hint to solve this

Answer (score 1):

When you create a weblogic domain, you define it will be started in Development or Production mode. 
 To modify that, update the value of production-mode-enabled to true or false in config/config.xml

For more details check the following link or Weblogic documentation.

[Difference between DEV and PROD mode in Weblogic 10.3](http://ananthkannan.blogspot.com/2009/06/difference-between-domain-dev-mode-and.html)

About your question on Weblogic Plugin, I suppose your're talking about OEPE (Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse), which will deploy your application to a running domain that will be in dev or prod mode according to the mentioned in the config.xml